# Rename files from in1.jpg, in2.jpg, in3.jpg, etc to out0001.jpg, out0002.jpg, out0003.jpg etc using perl script `rename`

Tags: linux, perl, rename

I would like to rename a large number files with names in1.jpg, in2.jpg, in3.jpg, etc to out0001.jpg, out0002.jpg, out0003.jpg, etc. Grateful if somebody would suggest a solution using the perl script `rename` (or `prename`) that comes with the perl distribution.

Comment: Have you already tried to solve this yourself? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Why exactly perl anyways?

Comment: @khajvah I search superuser and found quite a number of answers to similar questions using bash and a loop over each file name is needed. I think `rename` should work and would be more elegant; just that I don't know enough about regex.

Comment: @slchk I got stucked on how to get the matched string passed onto the replacement string. I experimented more and found  `rename 's/in([1-9]).jpg/out000\1.jpg/' *.jpg`.  Probably there are more elegant solutions. In perl, TMTOWTDI. :-)

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is a minor variation on the only example in the `rename` man page.

Comment: Yes. Really a problem of regex. The above is not (yet) the solution I need. I want in12.jpg to be renamed out0012.jpg and in345.jpg to be renamed out0345.jpg.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun and for free...

I'd use links as to retain the original names, but you can change the link command (`ln`) to a move command (`mv`) if you wish (added as a comment):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
    # Creates link files with ascending sequence numbers ($USE_SEQ=1) or original numbers
    # ($USE_SEQ=0):
    $USE_SEQ       = 1;

    unless(opendir(DIRECTORY,".")) { die "Unable to open current directory.\n"; }
    @files = readdir(DIRECTORY);
    closedir(DIRECTORY);

    $seqnum = 1;
    foreach $file (@files) {
        if ($file =~ /\.jpg$/i) {
            ($number) = ($file =~ /(\d+).jpg/i);
            $number = $seqnum++ if $USE_SEQ;
            $padded_number = sprintf "%05d", $number;
            $padded_name = "out" . $padded_number . ".jpg";
            `ln -s "$file" $padded_name`;
            # `mv "$file" $padded_name`;  # untested
        }
    }
```